# Remove <div><br> from WKwebview in objective C

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview

I have string :

```
<div><br/><div><br/><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;"><br/><div data-tid="messageBodyContainer"><br/><div data-tid="messageBodyContent"><br/><div>Thanks for agreeing to participate in our online bulletin board </div><br/><div><br/></div><br/><div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div>
```

It consist of lots of and 
 .
This string is coming from the server.So it is not always fixed.
I need to write some dynamic logic that if it contain mulitple div and br then only it will get remove.

Comment: Where are you running into problems?  Have any code to share?  This would be a custom built scrubber to get the string you're expecting.

Comment: I am getting it from server side. It is the way user had formated .I just wanted to remove the Div and BR tags from starting and end of the statement and not in between

Answer (score 1):

If you get the html as a string, you can parse it using regex

```
// Original string
let htmlString = "<div><br/><div><br/><div style=\"box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\"><br/><div data-tid=\"messageBodyContainer\"><br/><div data-tid=\"messageBodyContent\"><br/><div>Thanks for agreeing to participate in our online bulletin board </div><br/><div><br/></div><br/><div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div><br/></div>"

do {
    // Let regex tell handle the html matching
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<.*?>", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)

    // Get the range for the html string
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, htmlString.count)

    // Replace the regex matches with an empty string
    let parsedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: htmlString, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: range, withTemplate: "")
    print("PARSED HTML STRING:\n  \(parsedString)")    

} catch(let error) {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Since you don't have any control over the server side response, if might be helpful to use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) library.  It's a good native interface for html.

**EDIT:**

Couple things: Sorry I missed the objective-c part of the question.  Thanks for taking Swift and running with it.  Second, if you're not wanting just the string with the html tags (I misunderstood the original question), your best bet would be to use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`.  Here's an example of it removing the first div and br tag.

```
NSString *removeFirstPass = @"<div><br/>";
NSRange firstPassRange = [htmlString rangeOfString:removeFirstPass];

if (NSNotFound != firstPassRange.location) {
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:firstPassRange withString:@""];
}
NSLog(@"Parsed String: %@", htmlString);
```

This will give you the first instance and replace it.  You'll want to find the right ranges and replace them as you see fit.  You'll need to know where they are in the range as well so you know you're replacing the right ones.

Comment: Thank you for the response.How can i do it in objective C ? will it remove the div and br from starting and end of the string ?

Comment: NSString *searchedString = "HTML string";
    NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
    NSString *pattern = @"<.*?>";
    NSError  *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSString *parsedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:searchedString options:0  range:searchedRange withTemplate:@""];
    NSLog(@"parsedString: %@", parsedString); It is removing all the tags.so removing also html formating

Comment: I want to remove just <div> and <br> from beginning and end. Not in between.also i don't want to remove the formatting done in HTML.

Comment: @iosdeveloper Sorry I added Swift, but thanks for translating it.  I edited my response as well with a little more detail.